# Triangular Asterism Trigonometry between Alnitak, Saiph, and Sirius?

Tags: star, distances, mathematics

I am using the [SIMBAD database](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/) for [Alnitak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alnitak), [Saiph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saiph), and [Sirius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius):

```
Alnitak ; FK5 coord. (J2000): RA = 05 40 45.527 DEC = -01 56 33.26; 
Saiph   ; FK5 coord. (J2000): RA = 05 47 45.389 DEC = -09 40 10.58; 
Sirius  ; FK5 coord. (J2000): RA = 06 45 08.917 DEC = -16 42 58.02;
```

What is the trigonometric relationship in degrees (length of sides and inclusive angles to four decimal places) between these three stars when they are used to form a triangular aterism?

Comment: I guess, to measure the length of sides, you should also give the distance.

Comment: Question is not clear. Do you want spherical triangle formulas? Or real space ones?

Comment: @Envite Since the OP mentions "in degrees", I'm guessing they are looking for spherical triangle formulas. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively straightforward application of spherical trigonometry.  (See also: [About coordinate systems and angle differences](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40943/about-coordinate-systems-and-angle-differences/48571#48571) and [Angular Distance Between Two Points on a Sphere](http://astrophysicsformulas.com/astronomy-formulas-astrophysics-formulas/angular-distance-between-two-points-on-a-sphere/))

The expression to compute the angle on the celestial sphere between to points is:
$$\Psi = \arccos\left(\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2\cos(\phi_1-\phi_2)\right)$$
where $\Psi$ is the angular separation, $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are the right ascensions of the first and second direction, and $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the declinations of the first and second direction.

| Star Pair | Separation (deg) |
| --- | --- |
| Alnitak - Saiph | 7.9203 |
| Alnitak - Sirius | 21.6568 |
| Saiph - Sirius | 15.6351 |

I am including my conversion of the RA and DEC to degrees in case I have made a mistake if anyone wants to check my computations.

| Star | RA (HH MM SS) | RA (deg) | DEC (DD MM SS) | DEC (deg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alnitak | 05 40 45.527 | 85.1897 | -01 56 33.26 | -1.9426 |
| Saiph | 05 47 45.389 | 86.9391 | -09 40 10.58 | -9.6696 |
| Sirius | 06 45 08.917 | 101.2872 | -16 42 58.02 | -16.7161 |